# How to determine the URL of a single-page application based on HTML code

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I need to scrap information from a webpage that uses single-page application code (https://www.rigzone.com/oil/jobs/search/) just load something in the "search" field and click the button, then use the arrows in the bottom to jump from page to page, you will notice that during that process, the URL displayed in the top bar remains the same. I assume (please correct me if I am wrong) that there is a way to reveal the URL corresponding to each of the pages with the different positions posted. Ideally I would like to determine those to open them within my script, extract the HTML code and with the aid of VBA xmlhttp extract the information I want. How can I do that?

Alternatively I could just find the element corresponding to the "Next" button in the bottom and activate it within the script that scraps the data, which probably is going to be much easier, but I am curious about the first way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some very ugly code that needs improving that uses IE and keeps clicking the Next button for the expected number of pages based on 20 results per page.

If there is a way to construct as POST XMLHTTPRequest I would go down that route. Even better would be if an API exists.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub LoopPages()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, t As Date, num As String, i As Long
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Const RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 20

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.rigzone.com/oil/jobs/search/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .getElementById("txtSearch").Value = "Health"
            .getElementById("txtLocation").Value = "Paris, France"
            .getElementById("btnBasicSearch").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4)
        t = Timer

        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            num = Split(Split(.document.querySelector(".rz-table-dd-sm + div").innerText, "of ")(1), Chr$(32))(0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While num = vbNullString

        'do stuff with initial page

        On Error GoTo errhand
        num = Round(CLng(num) / RESULTS_PER_PAGE, 0)
        num = IIf(num < 1, 1, num)

        For i = 1 To num          
            .document.querySelector(".next").Click        
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend            
            'other code with new page               
        Next   
        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later   
errhand:
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

The CSS selector combination is

```
.rz-table-dd-sm + div
```

This uses the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `"+"` to select the `div` next to the element with class `rz-table-dd-sm`. `"."` is the class selector.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it doesn't answer the question about how to get the "hidden" url code, probably the right answer is that it is not possible to do it. On the other hand, your code allowed me to loop through the pages and extract the information required. Thanks again for that. There is a piece of the code that I don't clearly understand, can you help me to understand it?:[meta]num = Split(Split(.document.querySelector(".rz-table-dd-sm + div").innerText, "of ")(1), Chr$(32))(0)[meta]

Comment: there isn't a hidden url. There are javascript generated links. I think it unlikely you can access these client side.

Comment: It is adjacent sibling selector ahttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors Updated answer with more info.

Comment: Does this answer the question?